# Задание: помогите найти случаи речевой избыточности/недостаточности и исправьте фразы

Tags: стилистика

Найдите случаи речевой избыточности/недостаточности и исправьте фразы. Определите, в каких стилях функционируют данные лексические ошибки?

1. Налицо незаконное растаскивание государственного имущества.
2. Перед своей смертью он долго болел.
3. Существующие расценки завышены.
4. За реальным ходом качественного выполнения принятого решения был установлен четкий контроль со стороны администрации.
5. Надо пропагандировать обмен имеющимся опытом.

*Я нашел только случаи речевой избыточности и получил следующее (правильно ли?):*

1. Налицо растаскивание государственного имущества.
2. Перед смертью он долго болел.
3. Расценки завышены.
4. За ходом выполнения принятого решения был установлен контроль со стороны администрации.
5. Надо пропагандировать обмен опытом.

**Случаи речевой недостаточности мне найти не удалось, но преподаватель говорит, что они есть. И что это за стили, в которых функционируют лексические ошибки?**

Comment: Читайте функциональные стили.

Comment: Многословие, или речевая избыточность, т.е. употребление слов и словосочетаний, несущих излишнюю информацию(Существующие) Правильно: ***расценки завышены***.

Comment: Слово в скобках лишнее.

Comment: Серж, я понял, что такое случаи речевой избыточности/недостаточности. Это видно из самих понятий. Случаи речевой избыточности я также нашел. **Я не смог найти только случаи речевой недостаточности.**
Как определить функциональный стиль по одному предложению?

Comment: Это я дал подсказку.

Comment: Речевая недостаточность – это пропуск в предложении необходимого слова. Речевая недостаточность часто порождает неясность высказывания и комизм, неуместный в официально-деловой речи. ***Больные, не посещавшие амбулаторию в течение трех лет, вкладываются в архив (речь в данном случае идет о карточках больных)***

Comment: Все верно, речевой недостаточности нет. Возможно, она есть в других примерах.

Comment: Блин, я прекрасно это понимаю. Мне не нужны эти определения. Я просто хочу найти предложение(я), в котором(ых) присутствует речевая недостаточность (а хотя бы одно должно быть). В вашем примере это очевидно. Однако я в упор не вижу таковых среди моих пяти предложений.

Comment: В ваших примерах нет речевой недостаточности.Р. н. - это пропуск того или иного слова в предложении. Возможно, речь идет об этом предложении.  ***Гражданин А. следовал по улице без опознавательных номерных знаков***.

Comment: Серж, гуглил сейчас и нашел страницу с аналогичными заданиями от моего ВУЗ'а. И только тогда я понял, что вы имели в виду, написав это предложение. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается, что написанный мною ответ, и был верным. Ошибка была в самом задании (было пропущено предложение, содержащее речевую недостаточность). Насчет стилей не уверен:

1. Разговорный стиль. Слово "растаскивание" используется в значении
   "растаскивать, разнимать", поэтому является разговорным.
2. Публицистический стиль.
3. Официально-деловой.
4. Официально-деловой.
5. Разговорный стиль. "Надо" - разговорное слово.

Благодарю Серж за оказанную помощь (см. комментарии).